# Bash Script to Backup MySQL databases starting with specified prefix

Tags: git, bash

Obviously if I google search, there are tons of results for bash scripts to back up your MySQL database.  I couldn't find this specific example though.

Say I start all my new web projects at dev.example.com/newprojectname

I also prefix all my tables for this project with that name, so newprojectname_posts, newprojectname_pages, etc.

Everytime I make a change, I want to run the command to back it up and specify the database and table prefix so, `command tablename prefix` so I have a .sql file to git push

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

tables=( $(mysql "$1" --silent -e "show tables like '${2}_%'") )

for t in "${tables[@]}"; do
    mysqldump "$1" "$t"
done
```

Then run it like this:

```
command databasename newprojectname >backup.sql
```

It will backup all tables starting with `newprojectname_` (note the included underscore).